# Avoid Index form Url with string parameter in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controler action like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string Id)
    {
    }
```

So actual call is like Report/Index/{string_param_value}

I want to avoid Index from this like Report/{string_param_value} and for that 
i did following change in Global.asax.cs

```
   routes.MapRoute(
      "Report_WithoutIndex",
      "Report/{Id}",
      new { controller = "Report", action = "Index" }
  );
```

But this one is not calling the Index action 
I tried this one then

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Index",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { action = "Index" }               
        );
```

And this one works for me But after this all other Actions are broken

SO what is the correct work around for making a call to Report controller wuthout mentioning Index in url

Comment: Post your entire `RounteConfig.cs`, Make sure your first route is preceded before the default route.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I have to put my custom route as the first line before default routing rule

Comment: Does your `Id` always numeric?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `RounteConfig.cs`, works for me -

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Report_WithoutIndex",
        "Report/{Id}",
        new { controller = "Report", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And my Controllers are -

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
        return View();
    }
}


public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string Id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I use `/Report/2`, I was hitting Report controller Index Action. When I use `/Home/About` I was getting to go to About Action of Home controller. And all other default routes are working as expected.